# (~ABC)+(A~B~C)+(AB~C)+(ABC)

Tags: booleano, álgebra-booleana

Estou tentando solucionar esta fórmula:

```
(~ABC)+(A~B~C)+(AB~C)+(ABC)
(~ABC)+(A~B~C)+AB
(~ABC)+A(B+~B~C)
```

Mas não sei como sair desta última parte. Eu sei que o resultado final tem que ser `a~c + bc`. Mas não sei como chegar nele.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comecemos com isso:

```
(~ABC)+(A~B~C)+(AB~C)+(ABC)
```

Vamos reordenar as expressões:

```
(~ABC)+(ABC)+(A~B~C)+(AB~C)
```

Vamos colocar o `BC` e o `A~C` em evidência:

```
BC(~A+A)+(A~C)(~B+B)
```

Toda expressão na forma `X+~X` é verdadeira. Logo:

```
BC+(A~C)
```

Nota-se que a sua expressão original `(~ABC)+(A~B~C)+(AB~C)+(ABC)` tem uma propriedade interessante: Ela diz exatamente quais são as quatro linhas da tabela verdade na qual a expressão é verdadeira, uma vez que cada subexpressão entre parênteses tem todas as três variáveis `A`, `B` e `C` exatamente uma vez cada.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. A fórmula eu tirei de uma tabela verdade. Por isso ela tem essa característica de dizer as 4 expressões verdadeiras.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Victor está muito boa, porém essa solução que lhe darei é uma continuação direta da sua.

**Propriedades básicas de Álgebra Booleana usadas.**

```
   A ( B + C) = AB + AC   (Distributiva AND)
   A + ( BC) = (A+B)(A+C) (Distributiva OR) /*Cuidado com essa propriedade,
                                              ela não existe na aritmética
                                              convencional*/

   AB = BA                (Comutativa AND)
   A ^ 1 = A              (Elemento Neutro AND)
   A + B = B + B          (Comutativa OR)
   A + 1 = 1              (Elemento Máximo)
   A + ~A = 1             (Involução)
```

Todas essas propriedades podem ser provadas usando uma tabela verdade.

**Passo a Passo:**

```
(~ABC) + (A~B~C) + (AB~C) + (ABC)
(~ABC) + (A~B~C) + AB                   
(~ABC) + A(B+ ~B~C)    (Seu Checkpoint)
```

Para sair desse ponto é necessário desenvolver B + ~B~C, vou desenvolvê-lo separadamente em (1).

```
(~ABC) + A(B+ ~B~C)    /* Por (1) */
(~ABC) + A(B + ~C)     /* Distributiva AND */
(~ABC) + (AB) + (A~C)  /* Comutativa AND, irei colocar o B no inicio*/
(B~AC) + (BA) + (A~C)  /* Distributiva AND, "isolar" o B*/
B(~AC + A) + (A~C)
```

Para sair desse passo é preciso desenvolver ~AC + A, vou desenvolvê-lo separadamente em (2).

```
B(~AC + A) + (A~C)     /* Por (2) */   
B(A + C) + (A~C)       /* Distributiva AND*/
(BA) + (BC) + (A~C)
```

Perceba que estamos a 1 termo da resposta:

```
(BA) + (BC) + (A~C)   /* Colocaremos um elemento neutro no primeiro termo */

(BA) (C + ~C) + (BC) + (A~C)    /* Distributiva AND*/
Você pode notar que se desenvolvermos (C + ~C) temos 1 que é neutro no AND.    

(BAC) + (BA~C) + (BC) + (A~C)   /* Comutativa AND, deixarei em ordem alfabética*/
(ABC) + (AB~C) + (BC) + (A~C)   /* Comutativa OR, juntarei os termos semelhantes */
(ABC) + (BC) + (AB~C) + (A~C)   /* Distributiva AND, "isolar" os termos*/
BC(A + 1) + (A~C)(B + 1)        /* Elemento Máximo OR */
BC + A~C //
```

**Justificativas**

(1) B + ~B~C

```
B + ~B~C          /* Distributiva OR */
(B + ~B) (B + ~C) /* Elemento Máximo */
1 (B + ~C)        /* Elemento Neutro */
B + ~C
```

Ou seja,  B +  ~B~C = B + ~C.
Você pode confirmar que B +  ~B~C <=> B + ~C usando uma tabela verdade.

(2) ~AC + A

```
~AC + A              /* Comutativa OR       */
 A + ~AC             /* Distributiva OR     */
 (A + ~A) (A + C)    /* Elemento Máximo     */
 1 (A + C)           /* Elemento Neutro AND */
 A + C
```

Ou seja, ~AC + A = A + C.
Se você comparar (1) com (2) verá que essencialmente justificamos a mesma coisa.

**Observação**
Acredito que ao fazer exercícios de álgebra booleana você pode acabar de dois jeitos: (1) Tendo uma sacada inicial, como fez o Victor, que resolva rapidamente o problema ou (2) Fazendo aleatoriamente e precisando usar diversas propriedades para alcançar a resposta ;)